# How to refer to an existing uid and gid in Ansible?

Tags: linux, ansible

In my playbook I install the amavis package. Later in a task I use the mount module to setup a ramdisk (tmpfs).

In order to let the tmpfs-ramdisk be owned by the uid and gid created during amavis package install (amavis-user and amavis-group, in /etc/fstab then using the options parameter) how do I find out which uid and gid was created?

Goal (something like):

```
/dev/shm /var/lib/amavis/tmp tmpfs defaults,noexec,nosuid,nodev,noatime,size=500m,mode=770,uid=112,gid=116 0 0
```

Or should I create the users before package installation to explicitly set uid and gid via Ansible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to just specify `uid=amavis-user,gid=amavis-group` in your /etc/fstab.  The linux mount program will [interpret them correctly](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87494/can-fstab-options-uid-and-gid-be-the-user-group-name-or-must-they-be-numeric).

Comment: This is true. I'll see in the future if it's always possible to avoiud uid/gid lookups (aka "knowledge"). Guess it's recommended anyway to not need it.

Comment: Hmm - not quite the answer - NFS exports doesn't look like it can deal with this for the anonuid and anongid settings.

Answer (score 5):

While Bruce P's answer is often a good solutions in some situations there is no way to just supply a name. Following Satish Koppisetty's approach here is some code to do it:

```
- name: get myuser uid
  getent:
    database: passwd
    key: myuser

- name: get mygroup gid
  getent:
    database: group
    key: mygroup
```

You now have two dictionaries (`getent_passwd` and `getent_group`), from which you can retrieve the data. The following code just outputs the ids:

```
- debug:
    msg:
      - "user id {{ getent_passwd.myuser[1] }}"
      - "group id {{ getent_group.mygroup[1] }}"
```

*A tiny bit of background*: this is the case because `getent` returns a dictionary that looks something like this:

```
{
    "mygroup": [
        "x",
        "1004",
        "some_group_member"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

See the Ansible module [getent](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/getent_module.html) with `database=passwd`.

Comment: Out of interest, why the downvotes? Bruce P's answer does seem easier in the context of this specific question, but is 'getent' a viable way for Ansible to get a uid in the general case?

Comment: I would appreciate a straight to the point answer on how to actually get the uid for a provided username with ansible.